# What are the steps that give rise to this following resistance equation for a diffusive transport of electrons?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, electrical-resistance, nanoscience

$ R = R_b (1 + \frac{\lambda}{L})$

Source - page 6 of this book: https://nanohub.org/courses/FON1/01a/asset/15698

Comment: The derivation in the book does not seem to make sense. How is it even possible to arrive at this equation?

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead. If you cite sources, please mention at least author and title instead of just a link in order to protect against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: Done. Please remove downtick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In equation $1.1a$ and $1.1b$ the author states that, $R = V/I$ and $G = I/V$. Which means that $R = 1/G$ (resistivity is the inverse of the conductance). To arrive at equation $1.8$ the author first takes the inverse of equation $1.3$ (mentioned in the text just above equation $1.8$):
$$G = G_B \frac{1}{1 + L/\lambda} \to 1/G = \frac{1}{G_B}(1+L/\lambda)$$
If we now substitute $1/G = R$ (and similarly we can define $1/G_B = R_B$) we arrive at equation 1.8:
$$1/G = \frac{1}{G_B}(1+L/\lambda) \to R = R_B(1+L/\lambda)$$